# How can I map a horizontal scrollbar to a div within the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have two divs on a page like this:

```
<div style="width:300px;height:100px;overflow:hidden">
  <div style="width:3000px;height:100px">
  some content
  </div>
</div>
```

and let's assume that the outer div is positioned somewhere in the middle of the page.

Is there a possibility to "map" the global document scrollbar to that div so it's possible to use the mouse's / trackpad's horizontal scrolling feature to move that inner div to left and right?

I hope it's clear what I am trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible to re-map the scrollbar's effected area.  However, you might be able to achieve the same visual effect by making a fixed position div (`position:fixed;`), and keeping it on top of the one that needs to scroll left and right. You'd have to make the two divs siblings instead of parent>child, which hopefully isn't a deal-breaker.

This way, the page's scrollbar would effect the 'child' div just as it normally would, while allowing the other one to remain locked in place.

Hope this helps